# Matrix multiplication, element by element

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is it possible to express Matlab operation  A.*B (multiplication element by element)

```
A.*B  = [a11 * b11, a12 * b12, ..., a1n * b1n; ...; am1 * bm1, ..., amn * bmn]
```

by a common matrix algebra?

Answer (score 3):

You mean the [Hadamard product?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Hadamard_product)